# JavaScript, start function when innertext changes

Tags: javascript

Im beginner in JavaScript and I have the following problem:

I want to start my function in exact moment when website object change its inner text.

```
    let abc = document.querySelector('.abc')
    
    function alert(){
        if (abc.innerText != "" ){
            alert("Hello")
        }
    }
    
    abc.addEventListener("DOMCharacterDataModified",alert())
```

And it is not working.

I tried "change", "load" etc. instead of "DOMCharacterDataModified" but it still does not work.

If someone know how to solve that problem, please help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Event "change" is only fired by form elements: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/change_event

The events like 'DOMCharacterDataModified' are mutation events which would work but as of now are depricated: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Mutation_events

The most recent implementation to deal with your issue is Mutation Observer API https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver

```js
// This snippet won't work because I was too lazy to write HTML part of the snippet
// It should give you basic insight in the Mutation Observer API
$(function() {
  var callback = record => {
    // Callback does not return event object but mutation record object
    // You can filter here for specific mutation type using record.type
    // Properties of mutation record https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationRecord
    console.log('mutation occruded!');
  }
  
  var observer = new MutationObserver(callback);

  // Here you can configure what you want to listen for
  // https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserverInit
  var config =  {
    characterData: true,
    childList: true
  };

  observer.observe($('#my-element')[0]), config);
});
```